# Model class with variable properties

Tags: c#, json, properties, model, httpresponse

I have an Api returning JSON data as response. This response is basically answers to a survey taken. We have multiple surveys. Each survey will have multiple questions which can be different from the other surveys. (Hope I make sense here)

I have created a model class from the response I get for one of the survey like follows :-

```
public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
    public string value3 { get; set; }
    public string value4 { get; set; }
    public int FileSystemObjectType { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public object someUrl1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeUrl2 { get; set; }
    public string TypeId { get; set; }
    public string DifferentValue1 { get; set; }
    public bool DifferentValue2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> DifferentValue3 { get; set; }
    public List<string> DifferentValue4 { get; set;
```

The properties DifferentValue1, DifferentValue2, DifferentValue3 .. are the questions that can be different for each survey. Right now this survey has 4 questions, but other surveys can have different number of questions. The rest of the properties remain same throughout the surveys.

Eg. Other survey can have a model

```
 public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
    public string value3 { get; set; }
    public string value4 { get; set; }
    public int FileSystemObjectType { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public object someUrl1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeUrl2 { get; set; }
    public string TypeId { get; set; }
    public string DifferentValue1 { get; set; }
    public bool DifferentValue2 { get; set; }
```

Is there a way I can make a generic model class where the properties for the question can be different but other properties are same?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a typical scenario for inheritance..

Create a base class with properties that you want to have for all surveys and then derive from that class and add properties for the individual questions to that child class.

Example:

```
public class SurveyBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeUrl { get; set; }
    public string TypeId { get; set; }

    //...
}

public class Survey1 : SurveyBase
{
    public string MyQuestion1 { get; set; }
    public string MyQuestion2 { get; set; }

    //..
}

public class Survey2 : SurveyBase
{
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public int Whatever { get; set; }

    //..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give me an example for this?